# How to convert string of key value pair to dictionary in python

Tags: python

Below is my code.

```
test_str = '1:20,3:4,5:30'
res = []
for sub in test_str.split(','):
    if ':' in sub:
        res.append(map(str.strip, sub.split(':', 1)))
res = dict(res)
print(res) // result {'1': '20', '3': '4', '5': '30'}
```

This gives me `dict` but with type `str` but I want to be type of int. How should I convert it?

Any leads, please?

Comment: `This gives me dict but with type str` >> This doesn't make sense. dict is of type dict. I assume you mean that you either want the key to be int, or the value to be of type int?

Comment: `res.append(map(lambda x: int(str.strip(x)), sub.split(':', 1)))` ?

Comment: ```res.append([int(i.strip()) for i in sub.split(':', 1)])```?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `eval` or `ast.literal_eval` appending opening and closing curly braces at the beginning and the end of your string representation.

```py
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval('{'+test_str+'}')
{1: 20, 3: 4, 5: 30}
```

Comment: please use `ast.literal_eval('{1:20,3:4,5:30}')`

Comment: [Why is using 'eval' a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice)

Comment: @Epsi95, I modified the code to use `ast_eval`, but both are identical; however, I also think using `ast.litera_eval` makes more sense since it evaluates the literal, not the actual code.

Comment: That's much simpler than I thought :-)

Comment: Also consider using f-strings instead of string concatenation, i.e. `ast.literal_eval(f'{{{test_str}}}')`

Comment: @Selcuk, I was thinking to use that, but it will unnecessarily create confusion due to the need of using double braces to be used as escape character.

Comment: @ThePyGuy One minor disadvantage is that this won't validate that its a key-pair (as in the original loop) ... eg it will happily return a **set** for the input `"1,2,3"`  (in Python3, in Python2 it will die on that input)

Comment: `dict(map(lambda x: x.split(":"), test_str.split(",")))`, not as elegant as `ast.literal_eval` but get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

```
s="1:20,3:4,5:30"
d ={}
l =s.split(",")
l1=[]
for i in l:
   l2 = i.split(":")
   l1.append(l2)
   l2 = []

for j in l1:
   d[j[0]] =j[1]
```

What this code does is that it first converts string into a dictionary spliting it by"," and then t takes each element of the list and converts it into the dictionary taking 1st element as key and last element as its value

Comment: This is a procedure you may use as a beginner as it doesn't involve use of many built in functions and develop logic